# Is there any way to have language independent controllers/views/actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, view, dry

I'm coding some web-applications in MVC, and I have a problem with something that has been on my mind for a time. The web-aplications I'm developing are mostly going to be used in Swedish, and because of the language I want to have my URL routing mapped against Swedish URL names.

- `mysite.com/products/details/1`
  (English URL)
- `mysite.com/produkter/detaljer/1`
  (Swedish URL)

Is there any way that you can have language independent URL routing that map against the same controllers/views/actions? Because I also want to have the same controllers/views/actions to be reused in sites in different languages, such as English.

The reason that I want to have the same language on the URL and the content on the pages is that it gives a easier understanding for the visitor and it increase the pagerank and search engine optimization.

Comment: Cant give you an answer I'm afriad, but good question.  In my opinion this is something that MVC frameworks need to take into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have one controller that all requests are passed to and then that controller redirects to the appropriate controller based on some kind of mapping logic.

Probably doing that is more effort than the results are worth though.

Comment: +1 for:Probably doing that is more effort than the results are worth though.

Comment: Thanks- the more I think about it, that probably becomes a definitely!